# Error when setting default value to entire new column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Code works however getting this error when trying to set default value =1 to entire new column in Pandas dataframe. What does this warning error mean and how can I rework it so I don't get this warning error.

```
df['new']=1
```

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: how did you create your `df`?

Comment: @MaxU original dataframe created from an SQL query with df.read_sql_query. Then I'm formatting df with a multitude of operations.

Comment: can you shed some light on `formatting df with a multitude of operations`?

Comment: @MaxU Here I'm making two copies of the original df (removesold and soldactive). When I try to create new column for removesold, I get no error but for soldactive, I'm getting the warning error  <br/>     removesold = df(df.ExitDate.isin(errorval)) & (df.DispositionStatus == 'Sold') & (af.AssetStatus == 'Resolved')]  <br/>    df = df.drop(removesold.index)
    soldactive = df[(df.DispositionStatus == 'Sold') & (df.AssetStatus == 'Active')]
    soldactive['FlagError'] = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should solve the problem:

```
soldactive = df[(df.DispositionStatus == 'Sold') & (df.AssetStatus == 'Active')].copy()
```

your code:

```
removesold = df(df.ExitDate.isin(errorval)) & (df.DispositionStatus == 'Sold') & (af.AssetStatus == 'Resolved')]
df = df.drop(removesold.index)
soldactive = df[(df.DispositionStatus == 'Sold') & (df.AssetStatus == 'Active')]
soldactive['FlagError'] = 1
```

you've created `soldactive` DF as a copy  of the subset (**sliced**) `df`.
After that you'are trying to create a new column on that copy. It gives you a warning: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame` because dataframes are value-mutable (see excerpt from docs below)

Docs:

> All pandas data structures are value-mutable (the values they contain
>   can be altered) but not always size-mutable. The length of a Series
>   cannot be changed, but, for example, columns can be inserted into a
>   DataFrame. However, the vast majority of methods produce new objects
>   and leave the input data untouched. In general, though, we like to
>   favor immutability where sensible.

Here is a test case:

```
In [375]: df
Out[375]:
   a  b  c
0  9  6  4
1  5  2  8
2  8  1  6
3  3  4  1
4  8  0  2

In [376]: a = df[1:3]

In [377]: a['new'] = 1
C:\envs\py35\Scripts\ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

In [378]: del a

In [379]: a = df[1:3].copy()

In [380]: a['new'] = 1

In [381]: a
Out[381]:
   a  b  c  new
1  5  2  8    1
2  8  1  6    1

In [382]: df
Out[382]:
   a  b  c
0  9  6  4
1  5  2  8
2  8  1  6
3  3  4  1
4  8  0  2
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
df.loc[:, 'new'] = 1
```

`pandas` uses `[]` to provide a copy.  Use `loc` and `iloc` to access the `DataFrame` directly.

What's more is that if the `'new'` column didn't already exist, it would have worked.  It only threw that error because the column already existed and you were trying to edit it on a view or copy... I think

Comment: still getting warning error with    df.loc[:,'new']=1
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s

Comment: this works for me with no problems.  what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: The copy is being made somewhere before `df['new'] = 1`, as that by itself does not produce a copy.

Comment: Thanks! I was using `new_df = old_df[['col1', 'col2']]; new_df['label'] =1` , and the error went away when I added a `copy().`  That is, I used `new_df = old_df[['col1', 'col2']].copy(); new_df['label'] =1`  and had no issues